# Is there a File.AppendAllText() in Java?

Tags: java, file

Is there some clean static method to just dump (append) a string to a file?

Comment: Hmm... Commons-IO provides a writeStringToFile, but it doesn't append. This may be a hole in Commons-IO's coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the closest I am aware of is:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fname, true);
writer.append(yourString);
writer.close();
```

It's not clean or static, but neither is it the most painful code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the [documentation for FileWriter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29). Set the second argument to true to append to a file.

Comment: That's not a clean static method, that's a block of code you need to write, cinluding stream handling, closing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PrintWriter` like this

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true); // true for append
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

printWriter.append(string);
printWriter.close();
```

[PrintWriter Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Edit: Sorry I didn't check the right Javadoc for FileWriter.
Nowadays it seems to have an append method.

So the PrintWriter isn't really necessary if all you want to do is append.

Comment: and then "clean static method" is where, exactly?

Comment: Write your own if you really need one. Java does not have it.